# Getting reliable statistics from Apache Server

Tags: java, php, apache, server-side, server-side-scripting

I have an Apache Server from which I want to get some statistics (like its uptime, start time, and such) to manipulate in Java. Right now I have a simple PHP webpage that finds out the uptime and start time of the server, echoes it in a page, and then I read that single line php page from Java, where I split the string, knowing what data is in which space.

But now I want to know stuff like how many times has it been down, and to do that reliably I would need a process in the server that registers that. My first thought was to periodically check that php page from java, and if I faced an IO problem, it would mean that the server was down, but it could also mean that the java side has no internet connection or something, so it's not 100% reliable.

So it seems I need to take all the data from the server side, but I don't exactly know how to do so. My idea was creating a process of some kind in the server that would periodically input the last time the server was up in a text file, and with that improve the php page to read it and show new data from it, and then I would read that file from PHP, but I have no idea how to do said periodic process in the server side.

Any help? Or some other posible solution?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to make use of the apache server-status page.

You will need to have `mod_status` enabled, then you'll need to add this to your httpd.conf file

```
<Location "/server-status">
    SetHandler server-status
    Require host example.com
</Location>
```

A machine-readable version of the status file is available by accessing the page http://your.server.name/server-status?auto.

From there you can parse it with your script fairly easily.

Full documentation on `mod_status` can be found here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_status.html

If you want to collect the stats and process them later, you could simply just add a cron job that runs every minute (or other timeframe of your choosing)

```
# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  * command to be executed

# Execute every hour
  *  *  *  *  * wget --output-document=apache_stats_`date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S`.txt http://your.server.name/server-status?auto
```

Comment: This is useful, but I can do this already from PHP. What I need is a way to keep that info (uptime, start time, current time) in a file at the server side and update it while the server is online, so I can gather the statistics later

Comment: see the updated response which shows how to do with this a cron job.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I looked around to learn about the cron job thing and if I understood correctly, it's in Unix... and I'm using Windows. Sorry, but thanks a lot for all your help!